# Cannot resolve an append string to list error

Tags: python, list, pandas

I'm trying to do something that should be simple... but it's not working. I think I'm overlooking a fundamental, but I can't for the life of me work out what it is.

I have a dataframe with some columns named after questions and other ones blank. I want to put together lists that tie together a named column with any following unnamed columns, and start a new list when the next named column comes along.

For example, with the following column names:

```
Name?   Age?   Unnamed 1   Favourite soup?   Unnamed 2    Unnamed 3   Turnip fan?
```

I'd be looking to generate these lists:

1. ['Name?']
2. ['Age?', 'Unnamed 1']
3. ['Favourite soup?', 'Unnamed 2', 'Unnamed 3']
4. ['Turnip fan?']

I thought I'd use something simple like this:

```
for col in dataframe.columns:
    if col[:7] != 'Unnamed':
        current_list = col
    else:
        current_list.append(col)
```

But it produces the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `current_list` is a obviously not a list...

Comment: As @cricket_007 said, current_list isn't a `list` object, and `str` object hasn't the append  method, you can see all methods of `str`objects [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

Comment: In other words, what do you think `current_list = col` should be doing? It's assigning a list to a string, looks like

Comment: Yep, as @Austin Hastings shows below. I'd missed the square brackets. A stupid mistake. I think it might be time for bed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a string in `col`. But you need for `current_list` to be a list, even if it's just list of one element.

Try this:

```
current_list = [ col ]
```

Comment: Wow. That's embarrassing. Thanks for the really obvious fix!